# `tabular` and `bidi` strange behaviour

Tags: tables, right-to-left, bidi

I am using `polyglossia` (arabic and english) and a conditional environment that I can turn off and on, representing the teacher's version.

In the MWE below, I have three single rows in `tabular` and I expect the output to be the same in each.

1. The first row uses `\textenglish` and gives the result I want and expect.
2. The second row uses the `begin{english}` environment but the RTL seems to be ignored.  I don't know why.
3. The third row uses the conditional environment, and its RTL is also ignored and the alignment is different again.

It is the behaviour of the third row I want to fix, but the first two are good for comparison.

I wonder if the `bidi` package might have a bug here, but I too newbie to be able to know for sure.

Here is the MWE.  The fonts are unimportant.

```
\documentclass[11pt,oneside]{article}
\newif\ifteacher
\teachertrue
% \teacherfalse
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[numerals=mashriq]{arabic}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic, Scale=1.00]{Times New Roman}
\newfontfamily\englishfont[Script=Latin]{Times New Roman}

\NewEnviron{forteacher}
{
\ifteacher
\begin{english}
\BODY\par
\end{english}
\else
\fi
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{rl}
ااا  ببب & \textenglish{aaa bbb} 
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{rl}
ااا  ببب &
\begin{english}
aaa bbb
\end{english} 
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{rl}
ااا  ببب &
\begin{forteacher}
aaa bbb
\end{forteacher} 
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a `bidi` package bug but I think you have a misunderstanding of when to use `\textenglish` and when to use `english` environment.

For short text (less than a line), you use `\textenglish` and for long text, you use `english` environment. The `r` or `l` column of a `tabular` can contain only short text so using `english` environment does not make sense and it will have no effect; what you are asking is equivalent to

```
\hbox{\begin{english}...\end{english}}
```

So in this case, you need to use `\textenglish` command. However, when you have `p` columns, you can use the `english` environment to typeset your text from left to right.

Comment: It is usual to answer with an MWE so that op and other readers can proof your answer without having to code themselfes ...

Comment: ok, i think I get it.  Use p{}.  This fixes the RTL problem in this question.  But it leads me to another problem.  I will post as a separate question.

Answer (score 1):

For this purpose you can just use primitives  `\beginL`  and `\endL`  which are used from `bidi` to write `left-to-right`  inside `right-to-left` sentences, you can take a look at [The e-TeX Short Reference Manual](http://tex.loria.fr/moteurs/etex_ref.html).

```
\documentclass[11pt,oneside]{article}
\newif\ifteacher
\teachertrue
% \teacherfalse
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[numerals=mashriq]{arabic}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic, Scale=1.00]{Times New Roman}
\newfontfamily\englishfont[Script=Latin]{Times New Roman}

\NewEnviron{forteacher}
{%
\ifteacher
\beginL
\BODY\par
\endL
\else
\fi
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{rl}
ااا  ببب &
\textenglish{aaa bbb} 
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{rl}
ااا  ببب &
\beginL
aaa bbb%
\endL
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{rl}
ااا  ببب &
\begin{forteacher}
aaa bbb
\end{forteacher}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: 1) so bidi is broken at this point?  and also (2) I think this solution only works for tables with single line rows.  If I change to paragraphs, it breaks again.

Comment: Isn't the `\par` redundant in the definition of `forteacher`? It can actually can makes TeX complain about `\endL or \endR problem (0 missing, 1 extra)...` if used outside of tabular (where `\par` actually means `\par`).